# Inserting data into MySQL table with only one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Script Name: <input type="text" name="scriptname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","escalate_test","database88","escalate_test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall)
VALUES
('$_POST[scriptname]";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is insert in the table `appslist` into the column `listall` (the only column in that database).

But I keep getting this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''43things clone script' at line 3

Comment: Your brackets are not looking balanced at `$sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall)
VALUES
('$_POST[scriptname]";`

Comment: it's this `'$_POST[scriptname]` and btw, don't use that. Read this =>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `('$_POST[scriptname]";` is 1. missing a closing `')` and 2. an invitation to SQL injection.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice with an API that considered unparameterized queries a syntax error... :)

Comment: I've thought about that countless times. @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Love it, +1.

Comment: Use [`this method`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60442/1415724) instead (under the mysqli method), if you're going to use `mysqli_`

Comment: I replaced `$scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$scriptname);` with `$scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['scriptname']);` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20775714/1415724) below. Details are all in there.

Answer (score 2):

You must close your brackets here:

```
"INSERT INTO appslist (listall)
VALUES
('$_POST[scriptname]')";
```

Comment: NO NO NO => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Yes, but he is asking about his syntactic problem, not about sql injection or any other troubles.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong and can be marked correct, but it's always good to mention injection vulnerabilities.  Then again, some people just need to learn the hard way ;)

Comment: As someone told me yesterday in an answer about a similar problem: "Berating people about mysqli versus mysql is tedious & ineffective. The scope of the question itself has issues that should be addressed."

Answer (score 2):

Here, do use the following which is a **safer method**.

To point out where you made your mistake, it was a missing quote `'` and a bracket `)` in `('$_POST[scriptname]` which should have read as `('$_POST[scriptname]')` (EDIT: As Dan Bracuk pointed out in his comment, thank you Dan.) however, using this method is prone to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Also wrapping your table name with backticks is suggested.

### EDIT:

Use the the following (inside commented code below) if you haven't declared your variable.

```
$scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['scriptname']);
```

Instead of: (Both are in the code below. Simply use the one you need)

```
$scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$scriptname);
```

PHP

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","escalate_test","database88","escalate_test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// use the commented one below if you haven't declared your variable.
// $scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['scriptname']);
$scriptname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$scriptname);

$sql="INSERT INTO `appslist` (listall) 
VALUES ('$scriptname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're right, AND a missing quote. I'll fix that, thanks for pointing that out to me. @DanBracuk

Comment: I've made a mention about that in an Edit (comment). @DanBracuk Your contribution is appreciated, thanks again Dan.

Comment: Feel free to retract your downvote, since this has been corrected. @DanBracuk otherwise, no biggie. Live & Learn, I always say. Merry Xmas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['scriptname']);
$sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall) VALUES ('$var')";
```

instead of this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall)
VALUES
('$_POST[scriptname]";
```

You missed `')` at the end of statement and ' ' in $_POST variable

Comment: Then, use this:
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['scriptname']);
$sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall)
VALUES
('$var')";

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_` and you're using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","escalate_test","database88","escalate_test");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $scriptname = stripslashes($_POST['scriptname']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO appslist (listall) VALUES('$scriptname')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: I saw that, which is why I deleted my comment.